# find match folders then copy files and subfolders

Tags: python, copy, directory, subdirectory

Am new in Python and would like to do a task... I need to compare folder names from two folders dirfolder1 and dirfolder2... compare the folders in them and if they match...copy files and sub folders inside that matched folder...

thanks for your help.

Daddih.

Comment: Do you mean just at the top level? For example would you want to copy dirfolder1/a/b into  dirfolder2/c/b?

Comment: Have you tried something? show some code and explain where are you stuck

Comment: @ABS they are in different drives.... @ FC have tried something but what i have is just displaying the sub folders in each folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
import os, shutil

dir1 = r'/path/to/dir/1'
dir2 = r'/path/to/dir/2'
copy_dest = r'/path/to/copy/dirs/to'

dir1_folders = [dir for dir in os.listdir(dir1) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir1, dir))]
dir2_folders = [dir for dir in os.listdir(dir2) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir2, dir))]

for dir in dir1_folders:
    if dir in dir2_folders:
        shutil.copytree(os.path.join(dir1, dir), os.path.join(copy_dest, dir))
```

Basically, walk through each directory creating a list of its subdirectories, compare them, and for the matches, copy them (using copytree in case there are any subdirectories) into a third location.

Comment: Ahhh, so you want to copy the _content_ from dir1 to dir2? Basically merge the folders?

Comment: Hi Aravenel, thanks for your input the code works.... can we have it like copy stuff from dir1 to dir2 instead of having to copy to another folder... thanks alot i do appreciate it.... think this would be a nice starting point for me to improve the 1st part i have.... thanx :-)

Comment: yeah that's the idea... may be I dint put it correctly.... and how could it handle the issue of windows if we have similar sub folders with in the dir

Comment: In that case you're probably going to want to use something like `os.walk()` to walk through dir1, and for each file, check if it exists in dir2, skipping those that do, and copying those that dont. Alternatively, you could take the [`shutil.copytree()` example from the official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#copytree-example) and edit it to effectively do the same thing--remove the `os.makedirs()`, and as you walk through each dir's contents, check if it exists and copy those that do not.